# Efficent insertion of not aligned elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, matrix

I'm using numpy **1.9** to work on a set of arrays. Assuming I have something like that I have two 2d arrays `A` and `B` and a 1-d array `C`, that looks like that:

```
>>> A
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> B
array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]])
>>> C
array([1, 3, 2, 4, 0])
```

My goal is to insert in A all elements from B, according to C. More specifically, if C at position 0 has a 1, B[0, 1] should be inserted after A[0, 1].

Here's the expected result:

```
array([[ 1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1, -1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1],
       [ 1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1]])
```

I tried to implement it like that, but it's not very fast:

```
for i in xrange(size(C, 0)):
    j = C[i]
    A[i, :] = numpy.insert(A[i], j, B[i, j])
```

There is a way to make it faster? (do it with a single numpy operation, like masks or something like that)

Comment: You're example results in an error (you can't assign a 6 element array to `A[i, :]`, which has room for only 5 elements).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Sorry, you're right, I wrote down example matrixes without thinking too much about it. I'm fixing :)

Comment: I've tweaked your iteration to work.

Comment: @hpaulj oh, thanks! I take a look. I'm preparing a test suite to get the faster solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a nasty one-liner?

First, the data; the arrays have the same shape as yours, but I've used integers to make the example easier to read.

```
In [81]: A
Out[81]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [82]: B
Out[82]: 
array([[   0,  100,  200,  300,  400],
       [ 500,  600,  700,  800,  900],
       [1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400],
       [1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900],
       [2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400]])

In [83]: C
Out[83]: array([1, 3, 2, 4, 0])
```

And here's the nasty one-liner:

```
In [84]: np.insert(A.ravel(), np.ravel_multi_index((range(A.shape[0]), C), A.shape) + 1, B[range(B.shape[0]), C]).reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1]+1)
Out[84]: 
array([[   0,    1,  100,    2,    3,    4],
       [   5,    6,    7,    8,  800,    9],
       [  10,   11,   12, 1200,   13,   14],
       [  15,   16,   17,   18,   19, 1900],
       [  20, 2000,   21,   22,   23,   24]])
```

Here's the broken-down version:

`A.ravel()` flattens `A` into a 1-d array, which I'll call `F`:

```
In [87]: F = A.ravel()

In [88]: F
Out[88]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24])
```

(EDIT: It turns out this first step--flattening `A`--is not necessary.  As @hpaulj points out in his answer, `np.insert` will flatten the array by default.)

`np.ravel_multi_index` is used to convert the desired 2-d positions into the indices into the flattened array.  The `+ 1` at the end is necessary because you want to insert the elements *after* the index given in `C`:

```
In [89]: insert_indices = np.ravel_multi_index((range(A.shape[0]), C), A.shape) + 1

In [90]: insert_indices
Out[90]: array([ 2,  9, 13, 20, 21])
```

`B[range(B.shape[0]), C]` pulls the desired values out of `B`:

```
In [91]: values = B[range(B.shape[0]), C]

In [92]: values
Out[92]: array([ 100,  800, 1200, 1900, 2000])
```

`np.insert` does the actual insertion and creates a new array:

```
In [93]: np.insert(F, insert_indices, values)
Out[93]: 
array([   0,    1,  100,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,  800,
          9,   10,   11,   12, 1200,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,
         19, 1900,   20, 2000,   21,   22,   23,   24])
```

Now just reshape that to get the final result:

```
In [94]: np.insert(F, insert_indices, values).reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1]+1)
Out[94]: 
array([[   0,    1,  100,    2,    3,    4],
       [   5,    6,    7,    8,  800,    9],
       [  10,   11,   12, 1200,   13,   14],
       [  15,   16,   17,   18,   19, 1900],
       [  20, 2000,   21,   22,   23,   24]])
```

Comment: Useful solution! Can it also be used for 3-dimensional matrix? I try for an hour but I can not find the right way to implement your solution without using any loop for an 800*600*6 matrix. I'd like to insert the third dimension elements entirely from B, according to this example. Can you kindly write a 3-dimensional version? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, some slightly more legible arrays:

```
>>> A
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> B
array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]])
>>> C
array([1, 3, 2, 4, 0])
```

Next, some mask shenanigans:

```
>>> ge_mask = C.reshape(-1, 1) >= numpy.arange(5)
>>> eq_mask = C.reshape(-1, 1) == numpy.arange(5)
>>> lt_mask = C.reshape(-1, 1) < numpy.arange(5)
```

And the coup de grâce:

```
>>> result = numpy.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1] + 1))
>>> result[:,0:5][ge_mask] = A[ge_mask]
>>> result[:,1:6][eq_mask] = B[eq_mask]
>>> result[:,1:6][lt_mask] = A[lt_mask]
>>> result
array([[ 1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

[Warren's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26228400/577088) just-posted answer seems like it might be better from a memory perspective. Not sure about speed. (I do think the above is somewhat more legible!)

Comment: Definitely more legible. :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try both approaches. Maybe I have to edit my post to add a more readable example matrix, like yours ;)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the corrected iteration:

```
A=np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
B=np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)*-1
C=np.array([1,3,2,4,0])

A2=np.zeros((5,6),dtype=int)
for i,c in enumerate(C):
    A2[i,:]=np.insert(A[i],c+1,B[i,c])
```

producing:

```
array([[  0,   1,  -1,   2,   3,   4],
       [  5,   6,   7,   8,  -8,   9],
       [ 10,  11,  12, -12,  13,  14],
       [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19, -19],
       [ 20, -20,  21,  22,  23,  24]])
```

This can be turned into a one liner as:

```
 np.array([np.insert(a, c+1, b[c]) for  a,b,c in zip(A,B,C)])
```

The equivalent terms in Warren's answer are:

```
c <=> c = np.ravel_multi_index((range(5), C), (5,5))
b <=> B.ravel()[c]
np.insert(A, c+1, B.ravel()[c]).reshape(5,6)
```

`np.insert` ravels `A` as a default.  For this small example, this `ravel_multi_index` is 2x faster than the row iteration.