# Insertion of non aligned elements in 3-dimensional matrices in numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm working with 3-dimensional matrices using **numpy 1.9** and **python 2.7.5**.
Here is an example:

```
>>> A
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])

>>> B
array([[[-1., -1., -1.],
        [99., 100., 101.],
        [-1., -1., -1.],
        [-1., -1., -1.],
        [-1., -1., -1.]],

       [[-1., -1., -1.],
        [-1., -1., -1.],
        [102., 103., 104.],
        [-1., -1., -1.],
        [-1., -1., -1.]]])

>>> C
array([1, 2])
```

I'd like to insert in A all elements from B, according to C.
Example: `c[0] = 1 => After A[0, 1, :] has to be inserted B[0, 1, :]`

Here is an example of the expected result

```
>>> D
array([[[1.,  1.,  1.],
        [1.,  1.,  1.],
        [99., 100., 101.],
        [1.,  1.,  1.],
        [1.,  1.,  1.],
        [1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[1.,  1.,  1.],
        [1.,  1.,  1.],
        [1.,  1.,  1.],
        [102., 103., 104.]
        [1.,  1.,  1.],
        [1.,  1.,  1.]]])
```

I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228138/efficent-insertion-of-not-aligned-elements-in-a-numpy-array) that is really similar to mine except that the solution are only for 2-dimensional matrix and I'm working with 3-dimensional.

Here is my solution but I get incorrect results:

```
C2 = np.repeat(C, 3)
r1 = np.repeat(np.arange(A.shape[0]), 3)
r2 = np.tile(np.arange(3), A.shape[0])
index_map = np.ravel_multi_index((r1, C2, r2), A.shape) + 1
np.insert(A.ravel(), index_map, B.ravel()[index_map]).reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1] + 1, A.shape[2])
```

Here is a correct, but slow, solution using a for loop:

```
A_2 = np.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1] + 1, A.shape[2]))
for j in xrange(np.size(C, 0)):
  i = C[j]
  A_2[j, :, :] = np.concatenate((A[j, 0:i + 1, :], [B[j, i, :]], A[j, i + 1:, :]))
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "I get bad results" mean?  Incorrect?  Correct but too slow?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I obtained incorrect results because I am comparing the results with the correct ones obtained with a for loop. Now I edit my answer posting the correct for loop

Comment: I would suggest actually displaying the desired result and the incorrect result -- perhaps with smaller arrays (say 4x3x2).

Comment: Your for-loop example fails for me, because concatenate gives 6 rows but A2 only expects 5 rows.  What's up with that?  Does it really work on your system just as you wrote above?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry, you are right, now I fixed it

Comment: @senderle I added the expected correct results with smaller arrays

Comment: Now I get `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3` for your example.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I changed the matrices to have smaller arrays (and made a little edit to the code), please update your A,B,C inizialization ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you need to insert several
elements sequentially, you need to insert them at the same position.
Compare:

```
In [139]: x = np.ones(5); x
Out[139]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

In [140]: np.insert(x, [1,2,3], 100)
Out[140]: array([   1.,  100.,    1.,  100.,    1.,  100.,    1.,    1.])

In [141]: np.insert(x, [1,1,1], 100)
Out[141]: array([   1.,  100.,  100.,  100.,    1.,    1.,    1.,    1.])
```

**EDIT:** The original answer included full unravelling/reshaping
back, but in 3d you need a lot of care to do it right.  There's an
easier solution that takes into account the fact that `np.insert` and
`np.take` accept "axis" parameter and allow multi-value insertion.
That still requires some reshaping, but it doesn't resort to
np.choose.  Also, note the `mi+1` argument to `np.insert` to insert
*after*, not before the chosen rows:

```
In [50]: mi = np.ravel_multi_index([np.arange(A.shape[0]), C], A.shape[:2]); mi
Out[50]: array([1, 7])

In [51]: bvals = np.take(B.reshape(-1, B.shape[-1]), mi, axis=0); bvals
Out[51]: 
array([[  99.,  100.,  101.],
       [ 102.,  103.,  104.]])

In [52]: result = (np.insert(A.reshape(-1, A.shape[2]), mi + 1, bvals, axis=0)
                   .reshape(A.shape[0], -1, A.shape[2])); result
Out[52]: 
array([[[   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [  99.,  100.,  101.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.]],

       [[   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [ 102.,  103.,  104.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.]]])
```

This was the original answer:

```
In [18]: ixs = np.repeat(np.array([np.arange(A.shape[0]),
                                    C+1,
                                    np.zeros(A.shape[0], dtype=np.int_)]),
                          A.shape[2], axis=1); ixs
   ....: 
Out[18]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [19]: mi = np.ravel_multi_index(ixs, A.shape); mi
Out[19]: array([ 6,  6,  6, 24, 24, 24])

In [20]: result = (np.insert(A.ravel(), mi, bvals)
                    .reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1] +1, A.shape[2])); result
   ....: 
Out[20]: 
array([[[   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [  99.,  100.,  101.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.]],

       [[   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [ 102.,  103.,  104.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.]]])

In [21]: result = (np.insert(A.ravel(), mi, bvals)
                    .reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1] +1, A.shape[2])); result
   ....: 
Out[21]: 
array([[[   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [  99.,  100.,  101.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.]],

       [[   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [ 102.,  103.,  104.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.]]])
```

Comment: I think there is something missing: your result is 1 row upper shifted compared to the correct one I posted in my question ;)

Comment: Yes, my bad. You were going to insert those rows *after*, not before. When calculating `ixs` you need to increment C. I'm going to update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Also, see the updated answer for an easier solution.

Comment: I'm not seeing any speedup compared to the original loop.  There might be some combination of dimensions where it is better, but not the ones that I've tried.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work as a replacement for the last line of your (non-working) vectorized solution:

```
linear = np.insert(A.ravel(), index_map + r2[::-1], B.ravel()[index_map - 1])
linear.reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1] + 1, A.shape[2])
```

This is like your vectorized solution but with a couple tweaks to get the indexing right.  The first key was to realize that I needed to "undo" your addition of 1 to index_map.  The next epiphany was that when you're inserting into `linear`, you need to offset the indexes in each row because as you insert elements the subsequent ones are moved back.  So while `index_map` is `[4,5,6,22,23,24]`, we actually need `[6,6,6,24,24,24]`, and I just reused/abused `r2[::-1]` for this purpose.

It also seems that `B.ravel()[index_map - 1]` can be simplified to `B[r1,C2,r2]`.  And a bit more simplification to eliminate the weird subtraction of `r2[::-1]` gives you:

```
C2 = np.repeat(C, 3)
r1 = np.repeat(np.arange(A.shape[0]), 3)
r2 = np.repeat(2, A.shape[0] * A.shape[2])
index_map = np.ravel_multi_index((r1, C2, r2), A.shape) + 1
linear = np.insert(A.ravel(), index_map, B[r1,C2,r2])
linear.reshape(A.shape[0], A.shape[1] + 1, A.shape[2])
```

Comment: Your solution is almost ok, it works with the example I posted before but not using a more general matrix: I found that your method gets always the last element of B and copy it in the result. Following the new example I get `array([[[   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [ 101.,  101.,  101.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.],
        [   1.,    1.,    1.]] [...]])