# Insertion of non aligned elements in 4-dimensional matrices in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm working with 4-dimensional matrices using **numpy 1.9** and **python 2.7.5**.

I am working with 3 numpy array `A`, `B`, `C` (this are ones array to semplify):

```
>>> A = np.ones((2,2,4,3));
>>> B = np.ones((2,2,4,3))*-1; B[0,0,1,:] = [10,11,12]; B[0,1,1,:] = [13,14,15]; B[1,0,1,:] = [16,17,18]; B[1,1,1,:] = [19,20,21];
>>> C = [[1,1],[1,1]]
```

I'd like to **insert in `A` all elements from `B`, according to `C`**.
Example:

- `c[0,0] = [1] => After A[0, 0, 1, :] has to be inserted B[0, 0, 1, :]`
- `c[0,1] = [1] => After A[0, 1, 1, :] has to be inserted B[0, 1, 1, :]`
- `c[1,0] = [1] => After A[1, 0, 1, :] has to be inserted B[1, 0, 1, :]`
- `c[1,1] = [1] => After A[1, 1, 1, :] has to be inserted B[1, 1, 1, :]`

I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248359/insertion-of-non-aligned-elements-in-3-dimensional-matrices-in-numpy) for 3D array but I cannot get the same results for 4D array (I'm quite new with numpy).

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with your for loop solution in the 3D case?  Surely you can extend that.

Comment: Surely it will work, but the for loop is much slower than a pure numpy solution, I need a solution as fast as possible

Comment: Have you done timings with the 3d insert solution?  With these small sample arrays it is slower.  What size of arrays are you working with.  Most importantly, how many terms in `C`?

Comment: Do you understand the 3d insert solution?  I'm not new to `numpy`, but it will still take me some time to digest it.

Comment: I tried the 3d solutions with `(200,200,200)` size arrays.  Your iterative solution was still more than 3x faster.

Comment: Shouldn't `C` be `[[1,1],[1,1]]`?  Or `B[0, 1, 2, :]`?

Comment: yes you are right, I corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reshape your arrays to 3d, and use the solution(s) from the previous question:

```
def fn_4d(A,B,C, fn):
    shape = list(A.shape)
    A = A.reshape(-1,A.shape[-2], A.shape[-1])
    B = B.reshape(-1,B.shape[-2], B.shape[-1])
    C = np.array(C).reshape(-1)
    A2 = fn(A,B,C)
    shape[-2] += 1
    A2 = A2.reshape(shape)
    return A2
```

If your iterative solution is

```
def iter_3d(A,B,C):
    A_2 = np.zeros((A.shape[0], A.shape[1] + 1, A.shape[2]))
    for j in xrange(np.size(C, 0)):
      i = C[j]
      A_2[j, :, :] = np.concatenate((A[j, 0:i + 1, :], [B[j, i, :]], A[j, i + 1:, :]))
    return A_2

fn_4d(A, B, C, iter_3d)
```

This reshaping is quite general, working for anything from the original 3d size on up - as long as the insert is in the `-2` dimension.

An alternative to your `concatenate` would be:

```
  A_2[j,:,:] = np.insert(A[j,...], i+1, B[j,i,:], axis=0)
```

but digging into `insert`, shows that it is essentially doing:

```
  A_2[j,:i+1,:] = A[j,:i+1,:]
  A_2[j,i+1,:] = B[j,i,:]
  A_2[j,i+2:,:] = A[j,i+1:,:]
```

Timings are about the same for these alternatives.

The 3d solution that inserts multiple rows at a time, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26252542/901925, uses, in effect, boolean mask indexing:

```
def insert_3d2(A,B,C):
    mi = np.ravel_multi_index([np.arange(A.shape[0]), C], A.shape[:2])
    bvals = np.take(B.reshape(-1, B.shape[-1]), mi, axis=0)
    # result = np.insert(A.reshape(-1, A.shape[2]), mi + 1, bvals, axis=0)
    # which does:

    mi += np.arange(len(mi))
    A1 = A.reshape(-1, A.shape[2])
    shape = list(A1.shape)
    shape[0] += len(mi)
    A2 = np.empty(shape,dtype=A1.dtype)
    mask = np.ones(shape[0], dtype=bool)
    mask[mi] = False
    A2[mask,:] = A1
    A2[mi,:] = bvals

    A2 = A2.reshape(A.shape[0], -1, A.shape[2])
    return A2
```

That is, it constructs a boolean mask to define where to put the rows of `A` in the new empty array.  Apparently there is little speed advantage to indexing over discontinuous blocks.

Here's a rewrite of the mask approach, without any flattening.  It's consistently faster than any of the other versions.  I have kept the iteration over `C` because that's the clearest way of looking at that parameter.  Replacing the enumerate(C) loop with vector operations similar to those used for `mi` and `bvals` yields minor time savings.

```
def insert_3d3(A,B,C):
    # without flattening
    shape = list(A.shape)
    shape[1] += 1
    A2 = np.empty(shape, dtype=A.dtype)
    mask = np.ones(shape, dtype=bool)
    for j,i in enumerate(C):
        mask[j,i+1,:] = False
        A2[j,i+1,:] = B[j,i,:]
    A2[mask] = A.ravel()
    return A2
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) to the rescue:

```
>>> C = np.asarray(C)
>>> D = np.ones((2,2,5,3))
>>> idx = np.arange(len(C))
>>> D[idx, C[:, 0], C[:, 1]+1] = B[idx, C[:, 0], C[:, 1]]
>>> D
array([[[[   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.]],

        [[   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [ 102.,  103.,  104.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.]]],


       [[[   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [  96.,   97.,   98.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.]],

        [[   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.],
         [   1.,    1.,    1.]]]])
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood, the matrices I'm referring to are examples (now I edited my question in order to clarify it), I'd like to insert in A all elements from B, according to C but A is a generic matrix, not a ones matrix.

Comment: Well then I am afraid your problem is seriously ill defined... To be able to insert those entries, you need to extend the shape of `A` by `1` in the third dimension. In the the 2D slices `A[0, 1]` and `A[1, 0]` that's fine, because we have something to insert. But what should be inserted in slices `A[0, 0]` and `A[1, 1]`?

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. Now I correct my question